# Comparing model to data to find the best fitting variable with scipy.optimize.minimize() [python]

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I need to compare a model to data to find the best fitting input. My data is surface reflectance of a body (= scattered light + thermal emission) at different wavelengths, and I simulate the reflectance by modeling the thermal emission part with Planck's law.  I need to find the temperature at which the modelled emission (and thus reflectance) fits the observations.

To do it, I define Planck's law as:

```
h = 6.626070e-34 # the Planck constant
c = 2.997924e+8  # the speed of light in vacuum
k = 1.380649e-23 # the Boltzmann constant

def planck(T):  # Planck's law for black body radiation
    intensity = (2*h*c**2) / ( ((wvleng*1e-9)**5) * (np.exp(h*c/((wvleng*1e-9)*k*T)) - 1.0) )
    thermal = 0.95 * (intensity*np.pi*D**2)/(SSI*1e9)
    return thermal
```

which returns the thermal emission of the body at different wavelengths.
Then, I defined the function that will qualify the fit (sum of squared difference between model and data at each wavelength):

```
def residuals(T): # 
  S = scat_light + 0.95*planck(T) # simulated reflectance
  return np.sum((reflectance - S)**2)
```

where T is the black body temperature. Finally, I use `optimize.minimize` to find which T leads to the best fit between S (simulated reflectance) and data reflectance:

```
x0 = 345.0  # initial guess, temperature is the only variable
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(residuals, x0, method='SLSQP') # optimization
fitted_temperature = res.x
```

Here's the problem: it gives me a temperature way below (~220K) than what it should be (around 340K), not fitting the data at all. Does anyone have an idea about why it doesn't converge properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be running into numerical problems. Any chance you can perform the computations in log space?

Comment: Is it possible that your equation for black body radiation is wrong? I'm seeing a different equation for Planck's Law of Black Body Radiation than what you have coded.

Comment: Intensity one is correct, but yeah, I might have an issue converting intensity [W./m²/nm] to thermal flux density [W/m2], I'll revise that. But is my way of using minimize correct? I've spent a whole day to figure out how it works and I'm still not sure if this part of the code is correct. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Getting tripped up on a few items here. 1) There are a few parameters in your `plank()` function which aren't defined: SSI and wvleng. Are these independent variables or constants? 2) what's the residual for? I don't believe `Scipy.optimize.minimize` cares about residuals - residuals are usually for trying to fit a function to data, not finding a function artifact (like the minimum). Finally, having data to work with would be nice :)

Comment: SSI (Solar spectral Irradiande) is the array containing the solar irradiance measured at different wavelegths (that are contained in the array wvleng). They are both constants. With residuals, I compare the observed reflectance ('reflectance', my data) to the simulated one ('S') and try to find the lowest difference (difference is the unnamed output of residuals). This is why I use minimize, to find for which value of temperature T the difference is the lowest.

Comment: What's the shape of these arrays? Also whats D?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I had several problems in my code:

1) In my `planck` function, my thermal emission relative to solar spectral irradiance is `thermal = 0.95*(intensity*4*np.pi)/(SSI*1e9)` instead of `thermal = 0.95 * (intensity*np.pi*D**2)/(SSI*1e9)`.

2) The biggest mistake, which gave me ~200K instead of ~300, was in my `residuals` function. The idea is to minimize the difference between the observed 'overall' reflectance spectra (= back-scattered light + thermal emission) and the simulated 'overall' spectra (correctly calculated as `S = scat_light + 0.95*planck(T)` in `residuals`. The error comes from the fact that this function returns the sum of squared differences between the BACK-SCATTERED light and the simulated OVERALL reflectance spectrum (=baskscaterred + thermal) : as the 'amount' of back-scattered light is much 'smaller' that the thermal emission at the studied wavelengths, it tried to fit a 'smaller' data (and thus explaining the low temperature fit).

I changed that and I now obtain a temperature of ~ 313 K that matches my observed overall reflectance curve very well.

Thank you all for your responses!

Comment: Glad you found an answer. If you found my thoughts helpful, please give a +1. I know it didn't get you all the way there, but I feel like the thoughts fell along the lines of the eventual solution.

Answer (score -1):

According to the `scipy.optimize.minimize` documentation x0 should be, "Initial guess. Array of real elements of size (n,), where ‘n’ is the number of independent variables." So you're guessing that a temperature of T=345 will minimize the sum of squared differences. This is then returning a single best T *for all T's in your data* (assuming you have more than one sample) to minimize this function. Since apparently you know the answer should be around 340K I would imagine that there is an error in your formulas leading into or out of the `planck()` function somewhere.

It also wouldn't hurt to look at the other attributes of the `res` output to see if there can be additional clues garnered there.